# I don't know what went wrong during the installation of my Conky, maybe you could help me

Tags: 14.04, gnome, conky

So today I reinstalled my Conky (theme), but something went wrong or I don't know. I'm using Harmattan conky. It has 4 modes and till today I used one which only showed the weather. Today I wanted to check out another mode which you can see on the image below, but as you can see it's "broken". 
Do you have any idea how to solve it? I tried to move it hoping that it will auto-repair/correct itself but nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening becouse `voffset` parameter of your conky cofiguration file is not adjusted well.

You will find many  `voffset` parameter in your config file like this `${voffset 50}`.

Increase the  first `voffset`  value, and it will shift the conky element down. Adjust it accordingly.

Comment: well, thank you but I just can't find these voffsets. I checked my conky.conf file but there's nothing like this.